# How to solve this diffusion equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I need to solve this equation:

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}= D \frac{\partial ^2C}{\partial x^2} +\lambda C $$

with :$ \frac{\partial C(0,t)}{\partial x} =0$ and $C(L,t)=0$  and $C(x,0)=\cos(\pi x/2L)$

I'm confused beceause if I try to solve it with seperation of variables , I still have the problem with the factor $\lambda$. 
I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: See at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3479918/stuck-in-solving-non-homogeneous-diffusing-equation

Answer (score 2):

The separation of variable $ C=T(t)X(x) $ gives
$$ \frac{T'}{T}=D\frac{X''}{X}+\lambda=A=constant. $$
The boundary condition implies $ X'(0)=0 $ and $ X(L)=0 $, so we first solve for $ X(x) $:
$$ X''+\frac{\lambda-A}{D}X=0 ,$$
so $ \frac{\lambda-A}{D}>0 $ and 
$$ X(x)=\cos(\frac{(n+1/2)\pi}{L}),\quad n=0,1,2,\cdots ;$$
$$ A=\lambda-\frac{(n+1/2)^2\pi^2}{L^2}=\frac{T'}{T} ;$$
and the last equation solves for $ T(t) $.

Comment: for wich λ is this a solution that doesn't change in time?

Comment: @wisk To know for what $\lambda$ this solution does not change in time, you can directly solve the equation by letting $\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}=0$: $$ D \frac{\partial ^2C}{\partial x^2} +\lambda C=0$$ and use the boundary condtition. But you can also use the last equation in the "answer" I posted to solve for $\lambda$: $$\frac{T'}{T}=\lambda-\frac{(n+1/2)^2\pi^2}{L^2}=0$$. Moreover, your solution needs to satisfies the initial condition so $n=0$ and $\lambda=\frac{\pi^2}{4L^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** you can hide $\lambda$ in the calculation by using the transformation $U=e^{-\lambda t}C$, then the equation becomes $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial t}=D\dfrac{\partial ^2 U}{\partial x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Laplace transform

$$
s C(s,x)-C_0(x) = D C_{xx}(s,x)+\lambda C(s,x)
$$

or

$$
(s - \lambda)C(s,x) - D C_{xx}(s,x)=-\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2L}\right)
$$

solving for $x$ with the boundary conditions we get

$$
C(s,x) = \frac{4 L^2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2 L}\right)}{\pi ^2 D+4 L^2 (s-\lambda )}
$$

and after inversion

$$
C(t,x) = \cos \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2 L}\right) e^{-\frac{t \left(\pi ^2 D-4 L^2 \lambda \right)}{4 L^2}}
$$